# How to get all pages from REST API newsapi.org?

Tags: java, rest, pagination

I am trying to create a program in Java that makes `http request` to `newsapi.org`, my task is to search for news by some criteria(country, keywords, category), which is something I am ok with.
My problem is that I have to use `pagination`, I mean I have some restrictions like every page must contain no more than 10 news.
My idea is to create a first request, I specify that I want the first page. When I get it, it conatins information about the number of total results that match my search.
And maybe later in a loop I should get all the other pages consindering I have the number of results.
I am not sure if this is ok. Can someone give me advice how to deal with that.

Comment: Check out Offset and Limit for pagination.